# Strange Convert.ToDateTime behavior

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Why is `Convert.ToDateTime` behaving strangely for the following values?

The following works just fine:

```
var value = "08/01/2011";
var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
```

The result is: `{08/01/2011 00:00:00}` --- which is just expected.

But now, when I do this:

```
var value = "07/21/2011";
var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
```

I get an exception:

`'Convert.ToDateTime("07/21/2011")' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'`

Comment: Your regional settings for dates probably are dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @Koen: How do I then check my regional settings and format my string value accordingly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"07/21/2011";
```

This is not a valid date, since `21` will be interpreted as the month.

Try explicitly specifying the format instead:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("07/21/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Edit:**

Agreed with @dtb's comment - I just couldn't find a culture where the date you specified is legal. But the general form is:

```
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime("07/21/2011", new CultureInfo("XXX"))
```

where `XXX` is the name of the culture you want to use (i.e. "en-GB" - which won't work with this format though)

Comment: Better: explicitly state the culture you're expecting the input to be formatted in.

Comment: @dtb: how can I get the culture info?

Comment: @Ruby: its usually country-specific - where about is the system you want to use this on?

Comment: `DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse("07/21/2011", new CultureInfo("en-US"));` works (July 21, 2011).

Comment: d'oh I guess I didn't try the obvious. This falls into the "can't see the forest for the trees" category

Answer (score 3):

Date/time strings are parsed according to the culture settings for the current thread (which is determined by the regional settings made in the Windows Control Panel).

For example, if the current culture is *fr-FR* or *en-GB*, then the input is expected in `day/month/year` format. If the current culture is *en-US*, the input is expected in `month/day/year` format.

You can find the culture settings for the current thread by looking at the [Thread.CultureInfo property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) of [Thread.CurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread.aspx).

If you don't want to parse a date/time string according to the culture settings for the current thread, you have to specify the culture settings explicitly.

Your input seems to be in *en-US*  format, while your system seems to be configured as *fr-FR* or *en-GB*. So explicitly specify *en-US* as culture:

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("07/21/2011", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
// result.Day   == 21
// result.Month == 7
// result.Year  == 2011
```

The reason why your first example works, is because `1` is a valid month, unlike `21`.

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("08/01/2011", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
// result.Day   == 8
// result.Month == 1
// result.Year  == 2011
```